# Longest word in a string

Tags: php, string

How can I get the longest word in a string?

Eg.

```
$string = "Where did the big Elephant go?";
```

To return `"Elephant"`

Comment: What have you tried so far? While someone may give you the answer, you'll learn a lot more if you try some stuff out first. (And, you're more likely to get a lot better answer if you show you've put some thought into it.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Loop through the words of the string, keeping track of the longest word so far:

```
<?php
$string = "Where did the big Elephant go?";
$words  = explode(' ', $string);

$longestWordLength = 0;
$longestWord = '';

foreach ($words as $word) {
   if (strlen($word) > $longestWordLength) {
      $longestWordLength = strlen($word);
      $longestWord = $word;
   }
}

echo $longestWord;
// Outputs: "Elephant"
?>
```

Can be made a little more efficient, but you get the idea.

Comment: You wrote that in 15 seconds?!

Comment: @JMCCreative: I'm pretty awesome.

Comment: heh you wrote almost exactly what i wrote...but quicker haha.

Comment: @Tomalak Your awesomeness should echo `$longestWord` instead of `$word` ;)

Comment: @dqhendricks: This question was definitely a race. :P

Comment: @JonathanSampson: But.. but.. it does! See! ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Fortunately the edit came in under the 5 minute mark, so no record of your non-awesomeness can ever be found ;) Nice work!

Comment: @FrankNwoko: Also you should be aware that "word length" here includes any punctuation. You can strip punctuation using the relevant string functions in PHP. I'll leave you to do some research on those at your own leisure.

Comment: @FrankNwoko: There was an update for a typo. Run the code as it is now.

Comment: @Tomalak: Still outputs "And,". Since when do words incorporate punctuation?

Comment: @mvds: If this is not good enough for you, feel free to submit your own answer!

Comment: @Tomalak: I see comments of you being posted and deleted in seconds, hard to keep track. About me: The `preg_split` based solution was already posted, no need to repeat that. I agree on encouraging personal research. But where is the fun of pointing a beginning programmer in the wrong direction? How must he fix "Goodness...A string with interpunction *within* a Tomalak-style-word!" without regexps?

Comment: @Tomalak: I know, for most of us this is all easy as pie, but in the end the regexp will be the essence of the solution (since you should either see `[^a-z]+` all as word-separators, or have to grep for `[a-z]+`), so it's kind of cruel to leave that poor OP under the impression that this would be a proper way to go about it, first picking one char (namely: the space) out of the separator subset, and only then process the countless others. ;-)

Comment: @mvds: Fine, I give up. This is a longest-token-finding example.

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** Here is another even shorter way (and this one is definitely new ;)):

```
function reduce($v, $p) {
    return strlen($v) > strlen($p) ? $v : $p;
}

echo array_reduce(str_word_count($string, 1), 'reduce'); // prints Elephant
```

---

Similar as already posted but using `str_word_count` to extract the words (by just splitting at spaces, punctuation marks will be counted too):

```
$string = "Where did the big Elephant go?";

$words = str_word_count($string, 1);

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
}

usort($words, 'cmp');

print_r(array_shift($words)); // prints Elephant
```

Comment: +1 for using `str_word_count()`. I would have placed the function immediately inside the call to `usort()` for brevity though. I'm a slave to jQuery conventions!

Comment: I don't like the need to create a function (and pollute the symbol table) though! `create_function` would fix that but then things are very verbose.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I don't like it either, but sometimes it is unavoidable (not saying that this is the case here).

Comment: @Felix I'm not sure what you mean by not having a reference to your array. I was suggesting `usort( $words, function( $a, $b ) { /* code */ } );` Should work with no problems. This was the method that @lonesomeday went with.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Ah I thought you mean to put the function `str_word_count` into `usort` :D I'd like to pass functions directly but I still tend to give answers in 5.2 style. It's more general and those aware of PHP 5.3 should be able to transform it...

Answer (score 2):

How about this -- split on spaces, then sort by the string length, and grab the first:

```
<?php

$string = "Where did the big Elephant go?";

$words = explode(' ', $string);

usort($words, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});

$longest = $words[0];

echo $longest;
```

---

**Edit** If you want to exclude punctuation, for example: "Where went the big Elephant?", you could use `preg_split`:

```
$words = preg_split('/\b/', $string);
```

Comment: @Tomalak Indeed, it's a fair bit slower. Still, it's an alternative, perhaps even prettier, solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
$array = explode(" ",$string);
$result = "";
foreach($array as $candidate)
{
if(strlen($candidate) > strlen($result))
$result = $candidate
}
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite useful function when dealing with text so it might be a good idea to create a PHP function for that purpose:

```
function longestWord($txt) {
    $words = preg_split('#[^a-z0-9áéíóúñç]#i', $txt, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    usort($words, function($a, $b) { return strlen($b) - strlen($a); });
    return $words[0];
}
echo longestWord("Where did the big Elephant go?");
// prints Elephant
```

Test this function here: http://ideone.com/FsnkVW

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to split the sentence on a common separator, such as spaces, and then iterate over each word, and only keep a reference to the largest one.

Do note that this will find the first largest word.

```
<?php
function getLargestWord($str) {
  $strArr = explode(' ', $str); // Split the sentence into an word array
  $lrgWrd = ''; // initial value for comparison
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($strArr); $i++) {
    if (strlen($strArr[$i]) > strlen($lrgWrd)) { // Word is larger
      $lrgWrd = $strArr[$i]; // Update the reference
    }
  }
  return $lrgWrd;
}
// Example:
echo getLargestWord('Where did the big Elephant go?');
?>
```

Comment: While the code provided answers the question, you could assume that people reading the question would not understand it, please, provide comments explaining what you are doing, since this simpler question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string ='Where did the big Elephant';
function longestWord($str) {
$str.=" ";
$ex ="";
$max ="";
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
{
    if($str[$i]==" ")
    {
        if(strlen($ex) > strlen($max))
            $max = $ex; 
            $ex ="";
    }else
    {
        $ex.=$str[$i];             
    }
}
return $max;
}
echo longestWord($string);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).