# how to return words with longest word in one vector R

Tags: r

new account here, i just wondering, i have vector called `words` with contain many words, i just want to find out the longest word based on his length, so i consider using `for` loop `nchar` and `if`
to find out the longest word

so after do some desk research, my code will be like this

```
get.longest.word <- function(words)
    {
    for (i in words){
        if(max(nchar(i)) {
            print(i)
        }
    }
           }
```

and it returns error

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:4:26: unexpected '{'
3:     for (i in words){
4:         if(max(nchar(i)) {
                            ^
Traceback:
```

since im new in R, could you guys pls see my code and where the wrong at?

my vector after i use `dput(head(words))` are like this

```
c("a", "able", "about", "absolute", "accept", "account")
```

Comment: `nchar` is vectorized. No need for a loop

Comment: first give an example of your vector eg paste the output of `dput(head(vector))` and then state what the results should be. You might not use For loop at all.

Comment: are loop to check every length in every word?

Comment: `get.longest.word <- function(words) words[which.max(nchar(words))]`

Comment: `x[which.max(nchar(x))]` will suffice where `x` is a vector with words

Comment: omg idk R is so simple actually, could you pls give the answer at answer section so i can mark your answer? @KU99

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract longest word in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132629/extract-longest-word-in-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach might be, in base R:

```r
x <- c("cat", "corn", "house")
x[nchar(x) == max(nchar(x))]  # [1] "house"
```

The above selects all indices of `x` whose length is equivalent to the max length.  It will return ties in the event that two or more words have the same max length.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `which` with `max(nchar())`

```
words <- c("a", "able", "about", "absolute", "accept", "account")

words[which.max(nchar(words))]
```

```
[1] "absolute"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option

```
v[order(-nchar(v))][1]
```